# Nginx redirect non-existant files on https to http with try_files

Tags: nginx

I've searched for the correct way to do this for a while.

On an https server when a non-existent file is requested redirect to the http server and request the same file.

eg.

https:// example.org/some_missing_file.html - redirect -> http:// example.org/some_missing_file.html

https:// example.org/existing_file.html - serve file

https:// example.org/SomeDir/missing_file - redirect -> http:// example.org/SomeDir/missing_file

https:// example.org/SomeMissingDir/ - redirect -> http:// example.org/SomeMissingDir/missing_file

This if based snippet works

```
listen 443 ssl;

#... more config

if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^ http:// example.org$request_uri permanent;
    break;
}
```

But "if is evil" - http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

So this is my attempt at a try_files version - which doesn't work.

```
   try_files $uri @redirect;

   location @redirect {
           rewrite ^ http:// example.org$request_uri permanent;
           break;
   }
```

I've tried numerous variations of this; proxy_redirects, return 302's - they fail to redirect or don't work when a file is in a subdir, or don't redirect the root if empty.

Does anyone have a bullet proof try_files based replacement?

(ps. spaces due to link checker not knowing about example.org!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /path/to/documents;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @redirect; 
    }

    location @redirect {
        return 301 http://example.org$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - yes that does it. Do you know why the "location / { try_files $uri @redirect; }" allows this to work? where without location / { it doesn't?

Comment: To be precise, `try_files` in the `server` context works for those requests that do not fall into any `location`. Since you have not showed complete configuration, so I assumed that you had locations that could catch all requests.