# Why nginx "return 301" and ”try_files“ fall into an infinite loop

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, conf

my conf code:

```
index index.html index.php;
location / {
    if ($uri = '/a/') {
        return 301 https://example.com/a;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
}
```

If url is `/a/`, 301 to `/a`, then `try_files` part, add `/` to `/a` end, become `/a/`.

Next step, I think it will try the `index` definition, become `/a/index.html`, and reach the file.

But actually, It tried `/a/`, and jump out the `location`, then goes into `location` again, to `if ($uri = '/a/') { ... }`.

Then an infinite loop.

Why, I just got confused.

---

What I want to do is

1. If request `example.com/a/`, jump to `example.com/a`, then to 2
2. If request `example.com/a`, show `example.com/a/index.html` (but url is `example.com/a`).

Anyone can help me to reach this?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/411941/nginx-redirect-non-existant-files-on-https-to-http-with-try-files

Answer (score 2):

It's doing exactly what it's meant to do.

You can never reach `/a/index.html` because you keep redirecting back to `/a` before this can possibly happen. When nginx processes this, it sees the directory on the filesystem and automatically redirects (correctly) to `/a/`.

You should remove this inappropriate redirect.

Comment: Did you mean when try`$uri/`, first `/a/` then `/a/indx.html`? (and `/a/` fires re-enter `location` back to `/a`.)

Comment: Yes, that's what your 301 redirect tells your nginx to do

Comment: @nanxiaobei You never got to try_files because if is processed first. And **you cannot strip the trailing slash when serving static content**. It is mandatory. Stop trying.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks. The nginx error shown was "infinite loop", so I think first `if`, then `$uri/`, then back to `if` - so as a loop. When `if` processed, changed to `/a`, so must be `/a/` again it'll back into `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ServerFault. You can do what's mentioned in the OP with the following code...

```
location / {
    if ($uri = '/a/') {
        return 301 https://example.com/a;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404; 
}
```

Please see the relevant question and accepted answer at [Removing the trailing slash from a URL with nginx](https://serverfault.com/q/597302/102173) .

Basically, we don't have to rely on `index` and rather serve `index.html` directly when `example.com/a` is requested.